# How can I create an Intent from class in a package to a class from different package?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Not sure how to explain this,hope you understand me.. Here is the problem :

I have a few packages in my app and I'm doing this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), com.example.app.Lol.class); 
startActivity(intent);
```

and his code is in class which is in package : `com.example.anotherone`

It's not possible as I saw, that's why I'm asking..what I have to do, so I can be able to create an Intent like the example above.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: It should work. What is the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are importing the class you want

`import com.example.anotherone.Classname;`

and pass Classname.class in your intent,

`Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Classname.class);`

And that your Manifest is updated with the correct name for the activity (com.example.anotherone.Classname).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start an activity from another application, you can do it by specifying the intent action. When you define the activity you want to start in its application Manifest file, you can set it's `<action/>` tag inside `<intent-filter/>` to whatever action you want. Then to start this activity from another application call

```
Intent intent = new Intent("your-action-name");
startActivity(intent);
```

Your application will be the only to answer on this action request and it will open. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't want to start the intent from another application, I have one application with a few packages..and I want to start an intent in a class from one package to get class from another package in one application..

Comment: @psychenaut, then you should only import the activity you want to start into the activity you want to start it from.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly I have to wrote for this example :

package name :  com.miss.miss
class name :  Activity1
description:  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Activity2.class);

package name : com.miss.miss.secondactivity
class name : Activity2
description:  doesn't matter 

What should I do in this situation?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @psychenaut, Intent intent = (Activity1.this, Activity2.class); startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 0):

1.At first import the class you want.
2.pass the class name with intent.
  For example:

```
import package.otherclassname.yourclassname;
Intent intent=new Intent(view.getContext(),yourclassname.class);
```